# In Linux, how do I know if an ACK is received to a certain TCP packet?

Tags: linux, tcp

Long story short: in Linux, how do I ensure that an ACK message is received for a certain TCP packet?

Full story:

I'm debugging an Asterisk/OpenH323 <-> Panasonic IP-GW16 issue.

An H323 connection involves two sessions: H225.0 and H245. These are just two TCP sessions, over which some data are transmitted.

Let's call them `Session 1` (for H225.0) and `Session 2` (for H245).

`Session 1` has well-known TCP port number of 1720, while port for `Session 2` is chosen at runtime.

Control flow goes as follows:

1. Panasonic calls Asterisk: it opens `Session 1` (TCP/1720) to Asterisk and sends a SETUP message over `Session 1`, which contains the `port 2` that Panasonic will listen to.
2. Asterisk sends Panasonic a CALL PROCEEDING message over `Session 1`
3. Panasonic starts listening on the `port 2`
4. Panasonic sends a TCP ACK over `Session 1`.
5. Asterisk opens TCP `Session 2` on `port 2`.

Order of steps 2 and 3 is important: Panasonic will not listen to `port 2` unless it has received a CALL PROCEEDING message on `step 2`.

But in OpenH323 code, `step 2` and `step 5` are only several lines away.

That's why connection `sometimes` works in debug mode and `quite never` works in release.

It is clearly seen in a packet dump. I made a series of experiments, and in 52 cases out of 52, if `step 5` goes before `step 4`, the connection fails; if not, the connection succeeds.

There are no other messages sent from Panasonic except that ACK in `step 4`, and it seems that the only way Asterisk may know that `port 2` is listened to is receiving that ACK.

Of course I may implement a timed wait, but I want a cleaner solution.

So the question goes again: after sending a message over TCP connection in `step 2`, how do I know if an ACK is received to the packet containing the message?

Comment: The message being ACKed doesn't tell you that any processing has taken place as a result of receiving the data, only that the data has been received by the TCP/IP stack. So you're trying to test for the wrong thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz this is an old question, but out of curiosity, what is the right thing I should have been testing for? What I was dealing with was a crappy old piece of hardware running an undocumented custom OS, and that ACK was the only way to tell the other connection was listened to, and, empirically, quite a reliable one.

Comment: @Quassnoi If the OS is undocumented and custom, you might well be out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, I'd say you would find that your `tcp_info` structure would hold a nonzero `tcp_info.tcpi_unacked`. You'd get this via `getsockopt(TCP_INFO)`.

Note: unstable interface apparently.

Comment: `tcpi_unacked` is actually the `Number of children ready for accept()` according to the [kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5b7c4cabbb65f5c469464da6c5f614cbd7f730f2/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L3858)

Answer (score 3):

A TCP-level ACK is sent by the operating system and can be sent before the data is read by the process. So if you receive the ACK it doesn't mean that the remote application acted on the message or was even notified of it's existence.

Just imagine: if TCP acks we're a message confirmation then the application should read() the message, process it (which can take a while) and then call a "read_ok" syscall. As far as I know this is impossible with the standard socket API.

You might be able to check if there's any unacked data with the SIOCOUTQ ioctl (man 7 tcp). But it's not reliable solution to your problem.

Are you sure this is how h323 is supposed to work? What if port2 is invalid or taken by another connection? A confirmation or error should be sent back.

Answer (score 0):

The timing sequence seems odd, although if the Panasonic is using a proprietary O/S that might explain it.

To clarify - AIUI - if the Panasonic was running a "normal" O/S, the ACK sent by it in stage 4 would happen immediately after the Panasonic's software has `read()` the data from the control TCP socket.

Similarly the OpenH323 code call to `write()` (in step 2) shouldn't return (*assuming that it's not a non-blocking socket*!) until the ACK from the Panasonic has been received by the Asterisk server.  **That** is how you're supposed to know that the ACK has been received.

Essentially it seems that the Panasonic isn't doing the equivalent of `listen()` on the second socket until after it has `read()` the `CALL PROCEEDING` message.  It looks like a race condition - sometimes Open323 will try to `connect()` before the other end is ready.

When this happens, do you get `ECONNREFUSED` at the OpenH23 end?

Comment: The `socket` is blocking, and all this stuff goes in one thread.

I thought that `send()` blocks only when the buffer is full, am I wrong?

I didn't look for exact code, but the Panasonic sends an RST/ACK packet in reply to SYN, so I think that yes, i get an `ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: ok - this was a bit wrong - I'll edit.  The ACK would normally be sent once the _O/S_ has received the packet, it doesn't rely on the application reading() the data.

Comment: The write call can return before all the data is acked.